# Compare two strings (jquery .text() and literal string)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out why this is not working. I'm sure the text is the same. They both return a string. But the if statement is always true even when it's clearly false!... Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

```
   for (var i = 0; i < $("#slider_2011 dd").length; i++) {
      if ($("#slider_2011 dd").eq(i).children("h1").text() === "text1" || "text2" || "text3"){
        $("#slider_2011 dd").eq(i).children("h2").text("text4");
      }
    }
```

Comment: You don't compare `text()` with `"text1"`, `"text2"` or `"text3"`, but only with `"text1"`.  `"text2"` and `"text3"` evaluates to `true`. So it is like writing `if ( ($("#slider_2011 dd").eq(i).children("h1").text() === "text1") || true || true )` which will be always `true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var whiteList = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3'];

$("#slider_2011 dd").filter(function() {
     return $.inArray($('h1', this).text(), whiteList) > -1;         
}).find('h2').text('text4');
```

Comment: Hey nicely optimized ...+1.But I think it will be heavy diet for user to understand.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($("#slider_2011 dd").eq(i).children("h1").text() === "text1" || "text2" || "text3") // will always return true as in or(||) condition you just checked for "text1" (non negative) Which will be considered as true always.
```

So you should be comparing your text value like ,

```
var txt = $("#slider_2011 dd").eq(i).children("h1").text();

if (txt === "text1" || txt === "text2" || txt === "text3") {
    $("#slider_2011 dd").eq(i).children("h2").text("text4");      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your **if** statement is basically wrong.
I see many have given you solution. But i want to explain you why its wrong.

So, you have given your if statement like this

> if ($("#slider_2011 dd").eq(i).children("h1").text() === "text1" || "text2" || "text3")

javascript reads it like this

> if ($("#slider_2011 dd").eq(i).children("h1").text() === "text1" || true || true)

So the condition is obviously true always.

**Because javascript internally will convert the "text2" and "text3" to a boolean value. When any non empty string is converted to boolean its becomes true.**

Answer (score 0):

Basic flaw in if condition. Check separately for each text1, text2, text3.
Get basics right.